# Что входит в мини фреймворк php?

Tags: php, фреймворк

Начинаю понимать как строятся веб приложения. Узнал про роутинг. Например у меня задача сделать сайт где 5 страниц, есть блок товары, и категории меню и все по сути, такой себе сайт визитка. И вот я новичок в этом деле хочу создать себе мини фреймворк(пока свой велик) на будущее для разработки. Там будет своя админка небольшая для заполнения товаров и подобного.

То что я знаю сейчас, есть роутинг суть его я понял, ЧПУ так же делается вместе с ним. Теперь нужно что то сделать с БД, пока все на процедурном, нужно будет добавлять, изменять, удалять, редактировать с БД. Как по толковей создать функции что бы их было 4 штуки (добавлять, изменять, удалять, редактировать) и как то по параметрам все это делать только с разными блоками сайта всего лишь 4 функциями. 
Думаю еще нужна функция для добавления файлов на сервер и удаления файлов с него.

Пока в голове у меня крутятся такие мысли. Что вы об этом думаете? Хотелось бы увидеть список того чего не хватает и желательно в порядке от самого важного. Или что бы вы делали по пунктам с первого и до последнего в рамках сайта визитки(на процедурном), на своем велике?

Comment: Раз уж вы дошли до той стадии, когда осознаете, что вам нужен более современный и мощный инструмент для работы, то почему бы вместо изобретения велосипеда не взять уже готовое и отлаженное решение в виде PHP-фреймворка? Новичкам в фреймворках и ООП отлично зайдет небольшой и легкий CodeIgniter 3, у которого, к слову, и документация хорошая.

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что я бы сделал - продолжал изучать язык программирования дальше, не останавливаясь на процедурном стиле. На нем далеко не уедешь. Изучение процедурного стиля - лишь этап на пути постижения дзена.

Т.е. пока о каких-то полезных в будущем наработках говорить рановато. Конечно, их можно будет использовать как основу для дальнейшего обучения, но не более.

И вы неправильно ставите задачу. Программирование - это средство достижения ваших целей. А ваша цель - это сайт. Поэтому, задачи первичны, а средства вторичны. Тем более, что последних может быть бесконечное множество.

И последнее, что хотелось бы сказать: если уж хотите писать свой мини фрэймворк, то, хотя бы, делайте это в ООП стиле. Или придумайте свой, круче чем ООП ;)